# SQL Server database project post deployment script size limit?

Tags: sql, database, deployment, vsdbcmd

We have a SQL Server 2008 database project created in Visual Studio 2010 that we currently have been using for our production database for almost a year and use vsdbcmd to deploy.  We have many default data scripts setup to run in the post deployment script. Recently we had to add some large scripts (about 80,000 records) and for some reason when we deploy during our unit tests or through Visual Studio the entire post deployment scripts simply do not run and there are no errors.

I'm wondering if there are any size restrictions for this but after searching as much as I could online I couldn't determine if this was the case or not.

Help!?  :)

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like the scripts aren't being run -- can you debug to confirm?

Comment: They aren't being run; that's the problem.  There isn't any indication as to why.  If I remove one of my scripts from the post-deployment everything works fine.  I also tested running the entire post-deloyment script manually with all of the files and it ran ok.